# Need to redirect 404 to the home page.

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I only have one 404 left and have no idea how to fix it. So I need to redirect that single page to the home page.

I need http://www.name.co.uk/blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/img/trans.gif to redirect to the homepage within the .htaccess file.

Many thanks

Comment: If in Wordpress, just create a `404.php` file in the stylesheet directory, if it doesn't exist, and put your testing error code there. There is no need to use .htaccess for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it.

Redirect 301 /blog/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/img/trans.gif http://www.name.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your .htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

It's work for me.